# Automatic dictionary generation - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program which outputs all permutations of a string of length *n* whilst avoiding a defined substring, of length *k*. For example:

Derive all possible strings, up to a length of 5 characters, that can be generated from an initial empty set, which can either go to A or B, but the string cannot contain the substring "AAB" which is not allowed.

i.e. base case of `[""]` is the empty set.
The dictionary would be - `A:{A}, B:{A,B}`

From the empty set we can go to A, and we can go to B. We can not go to a B after an A but we can go to an A after a B. And both A and B can access themselves

example output: a,b,aa,bb,ba,aaa,bbb,baa,bba ... etc

How would I go about prompting a user to define a substring to avoid, and from that generate a dictionary which abides to these rules?

Any help or clarification would be greatly received.

Regards,
rkhad

Comment: I am trying to, when given, a set of strings be able to print out all strings which avoid a given substring. I have to manually define the dictionary, as in my original post, and it then prints out the possible permutations.

This is not homework but an area of research for my dissertation.
I am researching ways in which when given an arbitrary string I can deruive a mathematical generating function which illustrates the relationship between the string and the substring. It is based on a mathematical prrof by Andrew Odlyzko.

Comment: I thought that automatic generation of a set of paths, using a dictionary, would be a simple way to derive possible strings.

Comment: I am wanting to generate the dictionary, the dictionary will just point to possible next states of current states. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `itertools` module has a useful method called `permutations()`:

(from http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

> itertools.permutations(iterable[, r])
>
> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
>
> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the
>   iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.
>
> Permutations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the permutation tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.

List comprehensions provide an easy way to filter generated permutations like this, but beware that if you are storing permutations of a large string that you will quickly get a very large list. You may want to therefore use a `set` to whittle down your list to non-duplicates. Also, you may find the function `sorted` to be useful if you intend to iterate through your "paths" in lexicographic order. Lastly, the `in` operator, when applied to strings, checks for a substring (`x in y` checks if `x` is a substring of `y`).

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('AAAABBBB', 4)]
>>> len(perms)
1680
>>> len(set(perms))
16
>>> filtered = [p for p in sorted(set(perms)) if 'AB' not in p]
>>> filtered
['AAAA', 'BAAA', 'BBAA', 'BBBA', 'BBBB']
```

I'm working on my dissertation right now too, in the area of Formal Languages. The concept of substring membership can be represented by a very simple *regular grammar* which corresponds to a *deterministic finite automaton*. To jog your memory:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

When you look into these you will find that you need to somehow keep track of the current "state" of your computation if you want it to have different "dictionaries" at different phases. I encourage you to read the wikipedia articles, and ask me some follow-up questions as I'd be happy to help you work through this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look into the permutations method within intertools.

Comment: I tried but I do  not have a high enough reputation at the moment. Rest assured if I ever meet the elusive 15 I will haha